# Calculating portfolio log returns

Tags: analysis

I deeply apologize if the question I'm about to ask sounds a bit witless. What is the accurate way to calculate logarithmic return of a portfolio consisting of several stocks? Should it be a sum of logarithmic returns or a logarithmic return of the sum of prices? I must admit that I've never really been into statistics and it's quite confusing. Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\log{\left(\frac{\sum_i{w_iP_{i,t+1}}}{\sum_i{w_iP_{i,t}}}\right)}
= \log{\left({\sum_i{w_iP_{i,t+1}}}\right)} - \log{\left({\sum_i{w_iP_{i,t}}}\right)}
\\
\neq \sum_i w_i \log(P_{i,t+1}) - \sum_i w_i \log(P_{i,t})
= \sum_i w_i \log\left(\frac{P_{i,t+1}}{P_{i,t}}\right)
$$

Log-returns are not linear. So the log-return of the portfolio would have to be the log of the ratio of the portfolio values (i.e. log of the weighted sum of prices).
Standard (arithmetic) returns are linear, so both operations are equivalent (return of the sum, or the sum of the returns. You should be able to prove it easily).

Comment: Oh, alright, it makes perfect sense. Thank you so much for an answer, I think it's clear now!